# Side of collision with rotation

Tags: c++, collision-detection, sfml

I have 2 rectangles and I want to know if its a `length` collision or a `breadth` collision. I will also need to know the rectangle that's acting as pivot. I have made a small illustration. Here, V2 is the pivoting rectangle. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could calculate the distance from each point to each line segment.

For both rectangles it would be 8 points and 8 lines, but you only need to test between points and lines on separate rectangles. Once you find the shortest distance from point to line, the rectangle that holds the point is the pivoting rectangle, and you can use the line's index to determine which side it's on.

Here is some material on calculating the distance between a point and a line.

> https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line

Comment: This is the correct answer but does there exists an existing library i can just plug and play?